# How to prevent code duplication when implementing a trait for lots of structs

Tags: rust

I have a trait called `Stoppable` that makes it possible to create struct instances that have their own thread and that stop this thread when they are dropped.

I have multiple structs that need to implement `Stoppable`. For example: `RtspClient`, `Decoder`, `Renderer`, `ImageProcessor`.

The problem is that to implement `Stoppable` for each of them, I need to add

```
should_continue: Arc<AtomicBool>,
run_thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
```

to all of them.

Also, I tried doing this:

```
fn should_continue(&self) -> bool {
    self.should_continue.load(Ordering::Relaxed)
}
```

but I ended up having to ditch it and use this function inside the while like this:

```
while should_continue_.load(Ordering::Relaxed)  {
```

because of the closure (otherwise it'd move the borrowed `&self`).

Take a look:

```
use super::decoded_packet::DecodedPacket;
use super::decoder::{Codec, Decoder};
use super::defaults;
use super::encoded_packet::EncodedPacket;
use super::stoppable::Stoppable;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::{sleep, spawn, JoinHandle};

pub struct DummyDecoder {
    pub on_consume: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send + Sync + 'static>,
    pub on_produce: Arc<dyn Fn(DecodedPacket) + Send + Sync + 'static>,
    should_continue: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    run_thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl DummyDecoder {
    pub fn new(
        on_consume: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send + Sync + 'static>,
        on_produce: Arc<dyn Fn(DecodedPacket) + Send + Sync + 'static>,
    ) -> DummyDecoder {
        DummyDecoder {
            on_consume: on_consume,
            on_produce: on_produce,
            should_continue: Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true)),
            run_thread: None,
        }
    }
}

impl Decoder for DummyDecoder {
    fn set_on_consume(
        &mut self,
        f: Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<EncodedPacket> + Send + Sync + 'static>,
    ) {
        self.on_consume = f;
    }
    fn set_on_produce(&mut self, f: Arc<dyn Fn(DecodedPacket) + Send + Sync + 'static>) {
        self.on_produce = f;
    }
    fn codec(&self) -> Codec {
        Codec::H264
    }
}

impl Stoppable for DummyDecoder {
    fn should_continue(&self) -> bool {
        self.should_continue.load(Ordering::Relaxed)
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        let on_consume_ = self.on_consume.clone();
        let on_produce_ = self.on_produce.clone();
        let should_continue_ = self.should_continue.clone();
        self.run_thread = Some(spawn(move || {
            while should_continue_.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                let encoded_packet = (on_consume_)();
                match encoded_packet{
                    Some(encoded_packet) => {
                        println!("decoder received packet!")
                    }
                    None => {}
                }
                //Simulate transform of encoded_packet in decoded_packet here
                sleep(defaults::default_timeout_stoppable);
                let decoded_packet = DecodedPacket { data: Vec::new() };
                (on_produce_)(decoded_packet);
            }
        }));
    }
    fn stop(&self) {
        self.should_continue.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}

impl Drop for DummyDecoder {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.stop();
        self.run_thread.take().unwrap().join();
    }
}
```

In C++ `should_continue`, `run_thread` and `fn should_continue()` would be shared in a common base class. I just want to confirm that there's no way to reuse these variables and functions, because I hate copying the same code over and over for the same class.

Comment: Why do you name `on_consume_`, `on_produce_` etc. with trailing underscores? Usually that means you're trying to avoid conflict with a keyword (like `move_`, `ref_`, etc.) but those names don't conflict with anything.

Comment: @trentcl you're right. I thought I couldn't name then simply `on_consume` but apparently it has no problems

Comment: You're thinking OOP while you should be thinking composition. Make a `struct Stopper<T>(T) where T: Stoppable`. Now the common fields and behavior goes to `Stopper` and the `Stoppable` trait is much smaller.

Comment: @mcarton `Stopper<T>(T)` is an enum struct? I don't understand, could you give an example?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, well, I really meant for you to implement `struct Stopper<T> { should_continue: Arc<AtomicBool>, run_thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>, wrapped: T }`. But to answer your question, `struct Stopper<T>(T)` would be a _tuple struct_.

Comment: @mcarton I'm lost. You mean my struct `DummyDecoder` would go inside `wrapped`? I've never seen this pattern